# Spring 3.1 Redirects to /login on session-invalidate even for public URL access

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

For Spring Security 3.1, I have the following mappings:

```
<security:http create-session="ifRequired" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">

  <security:intercept-url pattern="/publicAccess" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

  <security:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="true" logout-success-url="/thanks" />
  <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login" session-authentication-error-url="/accessdenied">
    <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login?session=expired" />
  </security:session-management>
</security:http>
```

The situation is that when I don't make an activity for some time or when I reboot my server, I am directed to the `/login` mapping. It is correct because of `invalid-session-url="/login"`. But it also redirects me to `/login` for a public URL access, such as `/publicAccess`.

I want the public URLs to open directly, even if there is no session or an invalid session. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using `session-fixation-protection="none"`.

```
<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login" session-fixation-protection="none" session-authentication-error-url="/accessdenied">
    <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login?session=expired" />
</security:session-management>
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why requests are redirected to the login page even when hitting a public URL is that you require the user to be anonymously authenticated. At the same time you don't have the anonymous authentication mechanism set up for the application. In order to set it up, you have two choices:

1. Use `auto-config="true"` to automatically include it.
2. If you don't want all the things auto-config brings in, use [`<anonymous>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-anonymous) under `<http>` to selectively enable it.

As you can see in the linked doc, [`<anonymous>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-anonymous) will add

> an `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` to the stack and an `AnonymousAuthenticationProvider`. Required if you are using the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` attribute.

Comment: It does not redirect every time I hit a public URL, only the first time after I start the server.